# How to focus my window when I double-click on NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, notifyicon

When I double-click on my application icon [like this](http://spunit.tk/x/doubbletapp.png), I want to get focus on the application. I've tried this:

```
private void noi_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    BringToFront();
    Focus();
}
```

But somehow it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BringToFront() doesn't do what you hope it does, it only arranges windows owned by the same application.  To get in front of windows owned by *other* applications you need to use Activate() instead.  Which often fails, you can't steal the focus away, but not a problem when you click on a NotifyIcon you own.  Fix:

```
private void noi_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Activate();
}
```